# Program Not Compiling Correctly In Ubuntu 14.04 and GCC

Tags: c++, ubuntu, gcc

I recently dual-booted my Windows PC with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and I'm using Code::Blocks as my IDE of choice and GCC as my compiler.

I'm a Java programmer learning C++ and I wrote a simple addition program that takes two numbers and adds them together. When I run the program I put in the first number then the second number and instead of telling me my answer, it skips that and I just hit enter and end the program.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  int thisisanumber;
  int thisisanothernumber;
  int outputnumber;

  cout<<"Please enter first number: ";
  cin>>thisisanumber;
  cin.ignore();
  cout<<"Please enter second number: ";
  cin>>thisisanothernumber;
  cin.ignore();

  outputnumber = thisisanumber + thisisanothernumber;

  cout<<"Your answer is: "<< outputnumber <<"\n";

}
```

Comment: It also sounds like this is closer to being a bug in your code than compiling incorrectly (or having to do with Ubuntu or GCC).

Comment: @DrewDormann The terminal window stays open when until I hit return.

Comment: Does it print "Your answer is\n", or nothing?

Comment: Have you tried using `cout << "something" << endl;`  `endl` flushes the output buffer, I've found output can get lost.  I just tried your code in Codeblocks and then OpenSuse Linux, it works for me.

Comment: ladm@ash:~/src/test> g++ -Wall !$
g++ -Wall main.cpp
ladm@ash:~/src/test> ./a.out
Please enter first number: 2
Please enter second number: 6
Your answer is: 8

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're running your program in an environment that closes the terminal window when the program has finished.  If you're using Code::Blocks, you'll want to take these steps.

Go to `Project -> Properties -> Build targets`

Make sure your target is of type `Console project` and you have checked `Pause when execution ends`.

Comment: I pasted your code, and it worked in Code::Blocks and under Linux

Comment: @Rob11311 that's wierd that it's not working for me. I guess I'll restart my PC and see if it works.